git pathspec directory glob including cwd
In a git pathspec, the pattern **/name.ext will match name.ext in any subdirectory, but not the current working directory. For example:
> git ls-files "**/CMakeLists.txt"
src/CMakeLists.txt
test/CMakeLists.txt

There seems to be no single pathspec to match all the CMakeLists.txt within the current working directory tree. It would be convenient to have the behavior of find:
> find . -name "CMakeLists.txt"
CMakeLists.txt
src/CMakeLists.txt
test/CMakeLists.txt

Since the usual idea of * in expressions is to match "zero or more", I would expect the normal behavior of git for pathspec **/name.ext to match the current working directory as the "zero" part of **, but it doesn't work like that. While it's possible to repeat the filename without glob (i.e., name.ext **/name.ext), this is cumbersome and error-prone. Is there a more convenient alternative?
